# Python regular expression to match # followed by 0-7 followed by ##

Tags: python, regex

I would like to intercept string starting with `\*#\*`

followed by a number between 0 and 7

and ending with: `##`

so something like `\*#\*0##`

but I could not find a regex for this

Comment: apologize there was an error on the searched pattern

I would like to intercept string 
starting with \*#*

followed by a number between 0 and 7

and ending with: ##

so something like \*#\*0##

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you want to allow **only** one # before and two after, I'd do it like this:

```
r'^(\#{1}([0-7])\#{2})'
```

It's important to note that [Alex's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889143/python-regular-expression/889154#889154) regex will also match things like

```
###7######
########1###
```

which may or may not matter.

My regex above matches a string starting with #[0-7]## and ignores the end of the string.  You could tack a **$** onto the end if you wanted it to match only if that's the entire line.

The first backreference gives you the entire #<number>## string and the second backreference gives you the number inside the #.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above examples are taking into account the *#*

```
^\*#\*[0-7]##$
```

Pass : *#*7##

Fail : *#*22324324##

Fail : *#3232#

The ^ character will match the start of the string, \* will match a single asterisk, the # characters do not need to be escape in this example, and finally the [0-7] will only match a single character between 0 and 7.

Comment: Whoops.  I think I assumed those * were mistyped Markdown syntax

Answer (score 1):

`r'\#[0-7]\#\#'`

Comment: I'm curious about escaping the '#'s. As I read the docs, the '#' is special only when re.VERBOSE is specified or in the (?#...) construct.

Comment: Yes, but it's best practice in RE patterns to escape all non-alphamerics that are being used literally -- safeguard against "upgrades" to the RE pattern language that might break non-escaped alphamerics, plus, help to the readers by letting them know that they need not look up whether some weird unescaped punctuation char has special meaning in a RE pattern;-).

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression should be like ^#[0-7]##$

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, the simplest regular expression you need is:

```
rex= re.compile(r'^\*#\*([0-7])##$')
```

The `{1}` constructs are redundant.
After doing `rex.match` (or `rex.search`, but it's not necessary here), `.group(1)` of the match object contains the digit given.

EDIT: The whole matched string is always available as `match.group(0)`. If all you need is the complete string, drop any parentheses in the regular expression:

```
rex= re.compile(r'^\*#\*[0-7]##$')
```

Comment: really I need all the matched string not only the single digit, but your suggestion is very usefull thanks